# Running a node app in ubuntu

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

I have a node application that I basically run in 4 steps since I also need to run MongoDB and Redis:

```
mongod --config=/etc/mongod.conf
service redis start
npm run local
npm run work-local
```

Right now I basically open 2 tabs, run Redis server (which runs in the bg) then I execute the mongod line which basically hangs there so I open another tab and execute a shell script containing both npm commands.

How can I make a script to make them all run with one command? If I disconnect from the ssh session it stops, but I want it to run forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to run all my node apps in one command while keeping them alive constantly. It was more than I was looking for, and I'm super happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

I used PM2 and it worked well. 
I used node to install: `npm install pm2 -g`.

1. Start and add a process for process management list:
   `pm2 start app.js`.
2. Show the list of applications under process management:
   `pm2 ls`.
3. Stop and delete a process from the list:
   `pm2 delete app`.

Great and working like a charm...